# I need help with /execute

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to use the /execute and detect air below the player and set the block to a barrier block and the destroy it one second later. in doing this I am trying to make a double jump mechanism but a the moment the commands are in separate blocks using comparators and repeaters this is fine on single player but not multiplayer friendly. I did some research and I got this:

```
/execute @e[type=Player] ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-2 ~ air 1 fill ~-2 ~-1 ~-2 ~1 ~-1 ~1 barrier destroy 0
```

But, this doesn't work and it comes up with

> `[11:52:19] Failed to execute 'detect' as mr_assley19`

If anyone could come up with any alternatives or how to fix the command that I've tried, then that would be great!

Answer (score 3):

To fix the command:

- `@e[type=Player]` can just be `@a`
- There is no air with a data value of 1, so the detect will never succeed; it should be 0
- The data value in `/fill` should come before the old block handling mode

So your command should be:

```
execute @a ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-2 ~ air 0 fill ~-2 ~-1 ~-2 ~1 ~-1 ~1 barrier 0 destroy
```

I'm not sure if this really does what you want it to though. There is no way to execute two separate commands in a command block, nor is there any way to have a delay in a single block.

Comment: Nicely explained +1

Comment: `@a` will select dead players, while `@e[type=Player]` will select only living ones. There _is_ a difference.

Comment: @sharpturn Not saying there isn't a difference, but that `@a` will work for this. In fact, it'll be better if barriers aren't left around from when people die.

Answer (score 1):

Detect syntax:

```
    /detect <x1> <y1> <z1> <x2> <y2> <z2> <TileName> <dataValue>
```

The detect command needs  block datavalue as well as the ID for the block.  The only valid metadata for air is 0.  1 will cause the detect to always return false because minecraft cannot find air with datavalue 1.

Fill syntax:

```
    /fill <x1> <y1> <z1> <x2> <y2> <z2> <TileName> [dataValue] [oldBlockHandling] [dataTag]
```

For the fill command, you just mixed up the dataValue and oldBlockHandling.

Final command should be:

```
    /execute @e[type=Player] ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-2 ~ air 0 fill ~-2 ~-1 ~-2 ~1 ~-1 ~1 barrier 0 destroy
```

Comment: these don't quite work because as soon as you jump it continually creates and the destroys the block leaving you in the air

Answer (score 0):

Scoreboard Setup:

```
/scoreboard objectives add LivingTime dummy
```

Inside of a fast clock (20 times per second clock):

```
/execute @a ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-2 ~ air 0 summon ArmorStand ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:"Target", Marker:1, Invisible:1}
/execute @e[type=ArmorStand,name=Target] fill ~-2 ~-1 ~-2 ~1 ~-1 ~1 barrier 0 destroy
/scoreboard players add @e[type=ArmorStand,name=Target] LivingTime 1
/execute @e[type=ArmorStand,name=Target,score_LivingTime_min=20] fill ~-2 ~-1 ~-2 ~1 ~-1 ~1 air 0 destroy
/kill @e[type=ArmorStand,name=Target,score_LivingTime_min=20]
```

The first command (ignoring the setup command) summons an armor stand with a custom name of Target at every player who has a air block 2 blocks below them. The next command fills the area 2 blocks below every armor stand that has a custom name of Target. In the third command, the `LivingTime` for every armor stand is incremented and when `LivingTime` is at least 20, the area 2 blocks below is replaced by air and the armor stand is killed, removing its `LivingTime`.

Comment: this doesn't work can you please expand on this

Comment: this dosnt work ill ask a question about it because it should

Comment: It sounds like this needs a bit more explanation, as the asker isn't quite understanding what it is you're telling him.

Comment: It was simply missing some quotes, I edited it and it should work now.

Comment: @user107110 This was an attempt to answer your question, however the original answer is extremely hard to understand and had command mistakes. Also, this uses a lot of command blocks as far as I can tell.